# NASM to GAS syntax using intel2gas

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

I have a code written in NASM syntax and is working well. I then used intel2gas to convert my NASM code into GAS. (used *-i* , the default which is intel to at&t format).

I never used GAS before, just pure NASM in all my assembly needs. I used intel2gas to learn the GAS code format. Now, I have some line in the converted GAS code which have warnings from intel2gas and was appended with a '*MISMATCH:* ' prefix.

I have managed the others like in the .data and .bss sections, but I still have these:

```
MISMATCH: "lea ecx, [array + esi]"
MISMATCH: "lea ebx, [array + esi + 1]"
MISMATCH: "mov al, [array + esi]"
MISMATCH: "mov cl, [array + esi + 1]"
```

What's the equivalent GAS syntax of the NASM lines above?

Why did intel2gas did not completely convert my code and had left several MISMATCH lines?

Please help, thanks!

---

Using Ubuntu 13 x86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lea ecx, [array + esi]
lea ebx, [array + esi + 1]
mov al, [array + esi]
mov cl, [array + esi + 1]
```

All these lines don't use constant offset from address stored in register. From the view of syntax translator, label addresses aren't known and it can't be sure what configuration does target compiler use.

Translation:

```
lea array(%esi), %ecx
lea array+1(%esi), %ebx
movb array(%esi), %al
movb array+1(%esi), %cl
```

Comment: Whoaaa! Thanks man! :D

I have a follow-up question if I may..
I have this line: `movb %cl, $byte[ebx]` that produces this error: junk '[ebx]' after expression, and invalid expression suffix for 'mov'

How should I approach this?

Comment: If the `byte` is a label declared somewhere in code, you shouldn't have `$` before its name, as it precedes constants only. BTW `[]` brackets aren't allowed in GAS syntax, so you can use this: `movb %cl, byte(%ebx)`. 
If you wrote `byte` as size specifier before `ebx`, note that it's either not valid and unnecessary at all. Suffix `b` after `mov` already contains this information.

Comment: ohhhh.. this movb is real handy. :D
Thanks so much! :D